# What is the Correct Approach to Solving a Limit that Tends to Negative Infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

So

$$L_1 =\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{3x^4+\cos x}{x^4+2x+9}$$

Given the even power in the numerator, and that $\cos x$ oscillates between -1 and 1, the numerator tends to $+\infty$ as $x$ approaches negative infinity.

But what about the bottom? Since $x^4$ approaches $+\infty$ and $2x$ approaches $-\infty$ (the former at a faster rate). In this situation, I'm not sure how to work out the limit for $L_1$.

Can anyone help?

Comment: $3x^4$ and $x^4$ dominate, so the limit is $3$

Comment: Infinity is stylized with \infty :)

Answer (score 2):

Since$$\frac{3x^4-1}{x^4+2x+9}\leqslant\frac{3x^4+\cos(x)}{x^4+2x+9}\leqslant\frac{3x^4+1}{x^4+2x+9},$$you can apply the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Even if in this case it is not an issue, to avoid any confusion with negative sign we can let $y=-x\to \infty$ then

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{3x^4+\cos x}{x^4+2x+9}=\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{3y^4+\cos y}{y^4-2y+9}=\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{3+\frac{\cos y}{y^4}}{1-\frac2{y^3}+\frac9{y^4}}=\frac{3+0+0}{1+0+0}=3$$

or directly for the given limit

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{3x^4+\cos x}{x^4+2x+9}=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{3+\frac{\cos x}{x^4}}{1+\frac2{x^3}+\frac9{x^4}}=\frac{3+0+0}{1+0+0}=3$$

Comment: The $2y$ term in the denominator has a sign error.

Comment: @Shaun Yes of course! Thanks, I fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Using *equivalents*, it is very short:

$3x^4+\cos x\sim_\infty 3x^4$, $\;x^4+2x+9\sim_\infty x^4$, so
$$\frac{3x^4+\cos x}{x^4+2x+9}\sim_\infty \frac{3x^4}{x^4}=3.$$